# Run C# in .Net and iOS in Xamarin or Mono

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mono, monodevelop, xamarin-studio

For last few days I was looking for a solution, to have one C# code, that could be run in two existing projects (Windows Desktop WPF and iOS application).  I wish I could build 2 libraries, one for iOS and one for .NET, with one C# code. Is it possible in Xamarin or Mono?
I made some research and it looks like there is no such project type in Xamarin, that I could build a library. So Xamarin libraries can be included only in Xamarin.iOS (C#) projects :(. Is that true?
Than I moved to mono, but it looks like there is no mono without Xamarin. Monodevelop no longer exists, but there is Xamarin Studio with the same story.
Summarizing, is there any way to run one C# code (as a library) in iOS and .NET application?
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is portable library as shown in your picture

Comment: Are you sure? I know I can use it in C# Xamarin.iOS project, but would this build iOS .a library to use it in pure, native iOS project in xCode?

Comment: Your question is "is there any way to run one C# code (as a library) in iOS and .NET application?" The answer is yes but you didn't say anything about Native code. Then no. But there are some options to do that. It is in prerelease (I think) called "embedding" and native references.https://blog.xamarin.com/unleashed-embedding-xamarin-forms-in-xamarin-native/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research, now I know the answer. One can not run C# code (as a library) in **native** iOS and .NET application in Xamarin (possible only when iOS app is build in Xamarin, but this is not the case). But... it is possible in Mono. Using monolib you can run C# code in C app.

Comment: Your research is obviously incomplete, where you simply ignore the most important tool, https://github.com/mono/Embeddinator-4000